# Query only for numbers in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

I am trying to get an average number of an key in a nested array inside a document, but not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is how my document looks like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "PlayerRoundData",
    "playerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "groupId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "holeScores": [
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "points": 2
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "points": 13
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "points": 3
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "points": 1
      },
      {
        "type": "RoundHoleData",
        "points": 21
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, the tricky part of this is that I only want the average of points for holeScores[0] of all documents with this playerid and this groupid.

Actually, the best solution would be collecting all documents with playerid and groupid and create a new array with the average of holeScores[0], holeScores[1], holeScores[2]... But if I only can get one array key at the time, that would be OK to :-)

Here is what I am thinking but not quit sure how to put it together:

```
var allScores = dbCollection('scores').aggregate(
    {$match: {"data.groupId": groupId, "playerId": playerId}},
    {$group: {
        _id: playerId, 
        rounds: { $sum: 1 }
        result: { $sum: "$data.scoreTotals.points" }
    }}
);
```

Really hoping for help with this issue and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with `includeArrayIndex` to get index and then use `$group` to group by that index

```
dbCollection('scores').aggregate(
    {
        $match: { "data.playerId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "data.groupId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$data.holeScores",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$index",
            playerId: { $first: "data.playerId" }, 
            avg: { $avg: "$data.holeScores.points" }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: It comes up with this error: Function aggregate does not accept parameters (object).? Any idea?

Comment: Perfect, it does the job. Have one question though. Is it possible to also get the playerid in the output of this before the array of averages?

Comment: @Mansa sure, modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  { "$match": { "data.groupId": groupId, "data.playerId": playerId }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "result": {
      "$sum": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$data.holeScores.points",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
)
```

Comment: It comes up with this error: Function aggregate does not accept parameters (object).? Any idea?